# Cmd+Less Than (10.8.2) not working after Xcode (4.5.x) installed

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

I had to reinstall my MBP recently. I stress Cmd+Less Than a lot for switching between Xcode's main window and the Organizer for documentation. The standard OSX-shortcut for doing that is Cmd + Less Than. After installing Xcode it didn't work any longer. I saw, that Xcode uses Cmd+LT for "Edit Schemes", a rarely used option. Even after deleting the shortcut for "Edit Schemes" in Xcode, Cmd+LT didn't work.

How can I get Cmd + Less Than to work again?

Mac OS X Mount Lion 10.8.2
Xcode 4.5.2

I have less than 10 reputation on superuser (acutally first post here), so I can't post the answer to my question. Would yo be so kind and upvote this question, so I can officially answer the question?

The question, as well as the answer is only correct, if you use German keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching a lot, I once more checked the keyboard preferences and it seems, that installing Xcode overwrites quite some shortcuts.

Within System Preferences -> Keyboard Preferences -> Keyboard & Text input, the shortcut for moving the focus to the next window was changed to Cmd + ´. Resetting the shortcuts showed, that it switched back to Cmd + Less Than.

So deleting the shortcut Edit Schemes in Xcode and setting the move focus to next window shortcut to Cmd+LT recovers the old setting.

You could reset all keyboard shortcuts as well and check for conflicts within Xcode.

The question, as well as the answer is only correct, if you use German keyboard layout! The reason is, that the default switching-shortcut is Cmd+Backtick, which, in German layout, is the Less-Than-key. So it's changed to Cmd+LT on German layout, which is ignored by Xcode.